# making a string resources automatically from .xml file doesn't work with me

Tags: android, android-studio

for Example : if i drag a text view to the layout and try to make a source to it in the string file and press the bulb choosing ([I18n] hardcoded string"New String",should use @string resource) 
it doesn't open any thing

Answer (score 0):

Go To **Res ->Values-> string.xml** in that file create your string like

```
 <string name="accept">Accept.</string>
```

and then in your TextView that is in xml write

```
  android:text="@string/accept"
```

this will work. and if you will move the cursor on a @string/accept and the press 
**CRTL** and then click, you will go to that string.xml file

if you want the shortcut then what you can do is

**Press The yellow bulb- >Extract String Resouse ->In Resource Name-> Type name for that string**

You can do that for only one TextView cannot add multiple at the same time for that you have to go to other TextView and then follow the same procedure.

Comment: thanx for answer but i know that .. i wanna make it work automatically

Comment: like when i made it at first time , pressing the bulb then the window will open and writing the string name and so on

Comment: no thing in the bulb except this message ( [I18n] hardcoded string"New String",should use @string resource) .... , i noticed that when i opened the android studio this message appeared (IDE internal error occurred ... click to see  details and submit a bug report ) and in the event long this statement (Execute command: Execute command) appears in red color every time i click the message in the bulb

Comment: @AhmEdAmmarr It Appears when first you click on the text and then the yellow bulb.Try it.